# Solr - custom text field is being processed as Long instead of Text/String

Tags: indexing, solr, schema, sitecore, custom-field-type

I'm running Solr 7.5 for a Sitecore 9.2 instance. I added a custom field type to the Solr schema (/conf/managed-schema.xml), so that I can search on string fields case-insensitively, based on [this post](http://pietervogelaar.nl/solr-3-5-search-case-insensitive-on-a-string-field-for-exact-match)

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have the field in my site's solr config:

```
<field fieldName="c_item_part_number_ci" returnType="string_ci">Feature.Products.ComputedFields.ItemPartNumberField,Feature.Products</field>
```

But in my Solr admin, it's showing as a LongPoint field, and when I try to index my items, I get an error, because I'm trying to pass text but it's expecting a number (the field is called Item Part Number but it can contain text, in this case "Compact-Item-20")

[image]

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">400</int>
  <int name="QTime">246</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">java.lang.NumberFormatException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=sitecore://web/{46730869-114b-47ab-9c71-218fbe858caf}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=sitecore_web_index] Error adding field 'c_item_part_number_ci'='CAB' msg=For input string: "CAB"</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Your field was probably not defined when the first document arrived, which contained a numeric value in the field. Since you haven't deactivated the schemaless mode, Solr will guess at the field type of any undefined field and add it, and since it looked like a numeric value, it as defined as a `long` field. Remove the field and add it as the type you want, then reindex your content. In general, the schemaless mode should be disabled in production.